# Mysql Update Query is not Giving Desired Result

Tags: mysql, php

In My **Php Code** I Have Query As

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS todayleads 
FROM `lead_data` 
where `date` = '$todate' AND lead_status = 1 
AND uid = '$userid' OR assign_to = '$userid'
```

When I echo Query it result me

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS todayleads
FROM `lead_data` 
where `date` = '2018-01-12' AND lead_status = 1 
AND uid = '3' OR assign_to = '3'
```

And Output Gives Mea All Data From Start to End. But **Expected O/p** is Only Data That have lead_status = 1 and uid = 3 Or  assign_to = 3.

Comment: There is an OR condition, use parentheses.

Comment: i also tried by using || instead of OR  and && instead of AND. Both Separately tried.

Comment: Is `(date = '2018-01-12' AND lead_status = 1 
AND uid = '3') OR assign_to = '3'` or `date = '2018-01-12' AND lead_status = 1 
AND (uid = '3' OR assign_to = '3')` OR `date = '2018-01-12' AND (lead_status = 1 
AND uid = '3') OR assign_to = '3'` you should correctly define your conditions

Comment: @McNets Not able to understand but First Check About Date that it is today or not. than check for lead status it is 1 or not. both are compulsary and than check in `uid` and `assign_to` whether from both have or any have 3 or not .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand according to your comments you should add a parentheses to your WHERE clause:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS todayleads
FROM   `lead_data` 
WHERE  `date` = '2018-01-12' 
AND    lead_status = 1 
AND    (uid = '3' OR assign_to = '3')
```

Comment: Thank you its working now But can you describe this more. means just comma can affect .?

Comment: Without parentheses it returns all records where assign_to = '3', it doesn't matter if date=some_date or lead_status=some_value. Parentheses forces the query to check for date=some_date and lead_status=some_value and (uid=3 or assign_to=3) as a single condition. I hope this help.